# How can I solve my hitTestObject Collision Null Object Ref Error?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I've been trying for days now to add a simple hitTest between my player class and some "buildings" without success.
I've tried adding the hitTest to the player class & when didn't work, the building class. I've tried variations of the code on both also with no luck. I've been reading tutorials for days & no matter what I try, nothing seems to work - so, I must be doing something so simply wrong that the common sense just eludes me.

I have three classes that could/should be affected by the hitTest: the player class, building class, &/or objectPlacer class.
For this question I have left player class untouched, thinking that later I will add a Boolean to it's movement based on the hitTest from the building class. The ObjectPlacer class is instantiated at start. It's function is to instantiate buildings, flora, fauna, etc...I' m leaving it untouched as well thinking, that the "building" class is where I want the hitTest to be applied.

Here is my building code:

```
package com.gamecherry.gunslinger
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class  BuildingsLeft03 extends MovieClip
{
    private var speed:Number = 1;
    private var startX:Number;
    private var startY:Number;
    private var stageRef:Stage;
    private var target:Cowboy;

    public function BuildingsLeft03(stageRef:Stage, startX:Number,   startY:Number, target:Cowboy)
    {
        this.stageRef = stageRef;
        this.target = target;
        x = startX;
        y = startY;

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);

    }       

        public function loop(e:Event) : void
    {
        y+= speed;
        if (y > 544)
        removeSelf();

        if (hitTestObject(target.hit))
        {
            trace("hitTestObject");
        }
    }






    private function removeSelf() : void
    {
      removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

      if (stageRef.contains(this))
      stageRef.removeChild(this);
    }       
}
```

}

This all results in the following output error:
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at com.gamecherry.gunslinger::BuildingsLeft03/loop()

What exactly am I doing wrong? I've tried everything I can think of (I'm new to coding) & if I'm not getting this error then I'm getting some other error.

I wanted to be respectful of the help I'm asking for by not posting all my code (it's nice enough for you all to try & help without having to read through three pages of my admittedly amateur code) but, perhaps shining more light on my ineptitude will help in narrowing down the problem.

Here is my player class code:

```
  package com.gamecherry.gunslinger
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import com.senocular.utils.KeyObject;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

public class  Cowboy extends MovieClip
{
    private var stageRef:Stage;
    private var key:KeyObject;
    private var speed:Number = 0.5;
    private var vx:Number = 0;
    private var vy:Number = 0;
    private var friction:Number = 0.93;
    private var maxSpeed:Number = 2;
    private var fireTimer:Timer;
    private var canFire:Boolean = true;



    public function Cowboy(stageRef:Stage)
    {

        this.stageRef = stageRef;
        key = new KeyObject(stageRef);

        fireTimer = new Timer(300, 1);
        fireTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fireTimerHandler, false, 0, true);

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);

    }

    public function loop(e:Event) : void
    {
        if (key.isDown(Keyboard.SPACE))
        fireBullet();

        if (key.isDown(Keyboard.LEFT))
        vx -= speed;
        else if (key.isDown(Keyboard.RIGHT))
        vx += speed;
        else
        vx *= friction;

        if (key.isDown(Keyboard.UP))
        vy -= speed;
        else if (key.isDown(Keyboard.DOWN))
        vy += speed;
        else 
        vy *= friction;


        if (key.isDown(Keyboard.SPACE) && key.isDown(Keyboard.LEFT))
        fireBullet();


        x += vx;
        y += vy;


        //rotation = vx * 12;

        if (vx > maxSpeed)
        vx = maxSpeed;
        else if (vx < -maxSpeed)
        vx = -maxSpeed;

        if (vy > maxSpeed)
        vy = maxSpeed;
        else if (vy < -maxSpeed)
        vy = -maxSpeed;

        //scaleX = (maxSpeed - Math.abs(vx)) / (maxSpeed * 4) + 0.75;

        //If Cowboy touches edge of screen - he bounces back
        if (x > stageRef.stageWidth)
        {
            x = stageRef.stageWidth;
            vx = -vx;
        }
        else if (x < 0)
        {
        x = 0;
        vx = -vx
        }

        if (y > stageRef.stageHeight)
        {
        x = stageRef.stageHeight;
        vy = -vy;
        }
        else if (y < 0)
        {
            y = 0;
            vy = -vy
        }


    }

    private function fireBullet() : void
    {
        if (canFire)
     {

        stageRef.addChild(new PlayerBullet(stageRef, x - 10 + vx, y - 10, vx, vy));
        canFire = false;
        fireTimer.start();
     }

    }

    private function fireTimerHandler(e: TimerEvent) : void
    {
        canFire = true;
    }

}
```

}

Here is my ObjectPlacer code:

```
   package com.gamecherry.gunslinger
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

public class  ObjectPlacer extends MovieClip
{

    private var Build01Timer:Timer;
    private var Build02Timer:Timer;
    private var CactiSet01Timer:Timer;

    private var build01Place:Boolean = false;// if true - addChild starts at first frame
    private var build02Place:Boolean = false;
    private var cactiSet01Place:Boolean = false;
    private var stageRef:Stage;
    private var target:Cowboy;

    public function ObjectPlacer(stageRef:Stage)
    {
        this.stageRef = stageRef;


    var Build01Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);
    var Build02Timer = new Timer(25000, 1);
    var CactiSet01Timer = new Timer(0, 1);


    Build01Timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, build01TimerHandler, false, 0, true);
    Build02Timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, build02TimerHandler, false, 0, true);
    CactiSet01Timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, cactiSet01TimerHandler, false, 0, true);

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);

        Build01Timer.start();
        Build02Timer.start();
        CactiSet01Timer.start();
    }


    public function loop(e:Event): void
    {
        BuildSet01();
        BuildSet02();
        CactiSet01();

    }   

    private function BuildSet01(): void
    {
        if (build01Place)
        {
        var Buildings01Right:BuildingsLeft = new BuildingsLeft(stage, 720, -624);   
        Buildings01Right.scaleX = -1;
        stageRef.addChildAt((Buildings01Right), 2);
        var target:Cowboy = new Cowboy(stage);
        var Buildings03Left:BuildingsLeft03 = new BuildingsLeft03(stage, 0, -720, target);              
        stageRef.addChildAt((Buildings03Left), 2);
        build01Place = false;


        }

    }

    private function BuildSet02(): void
    {

        if (build02Place)
        {

        var Buildings04Left:BuildingsLeft04 = new BuildingsLeft04(stage, 0, -800);
        stageRef.addChildAt((Buildings04Left), 2);
        build02Place = false;
        }
    }

    private function CactiSet01(): void
    {
        if (cactiSet01Place)
        {
            var cactus01:GScactus01 = new GScactus01(stage, 0, 300);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus01), 2);
            var cactus01b:GScactus01 = new GScactus01(stage, 190, 50);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus01b), 2);
            var cactus01c:GScactus01 = new GScactus01(stage, 660, -40);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus01c), 2);
            cactus01c.scaleX = -1;
            var cactus01d:GScactus01 = new GScactus01(stage, 710, 340);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus01d), 2);
            cactus01d.scaleX = -1;
            var cactus02:GScactus02 = new GScactus02(stage, 420, -50);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus02), 2);
            var cactus02b:GScactus02 = new GScactus02(stage, 600, 180);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus02b), 2);
            var cactus02c:GScactus02 = new GScactus02(stage, 300, 240);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus02c), 2);
            var cactus03:GScactus03 = new GScactus03(stage, 540, 100);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus03), 2);
            var cactus03b:GScactus03 = new GScactus03(stage, 30, 5);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus03b), 2);
            cactus03b.scaleX = -1;
            var cactus03c:GScactus03 = new GScactus03(stage, 520, 420);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus03c), 2);

            cactiSet01Place = false;
        }
    }



    private function build01TimerHandler(e: TimerEvent) : void
    {
        build01Place = true;
    }
    private function build02TimerHandler(e: TimerEvent) : void
    {
        build02Place = true;
    }


    private function cactiSet01TimerHandler(e: TimerEvent) : void
    {
        cactiSet01Place = true;
    }











    private function removeSelf() : void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

        if (stageRef.contains(this))
        stageRef.removeChild(this); 
    }   



















}
```

}

Obviously there is more actionscript files that interact with these files but, these should be the only ones affected by a "hitTest"

Comment: We would probably need to see the code where the BuildingsLeft03 constructor is called to find the mistake. As Sam pointed out, the only way this Error can occur is if you are passing in a reference to a null object as the target:Cowboy argument. You need to make sure that you are initializing the variable that you are passing as target to BuildingsLeft03 constructor _before_ calling it.

Comment: I added the other mentioned as files. I hope this is not too overwhelming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to your Error 1009, the loop() method contains a

```
target.hit
```

reference, the only potential I see for a null pointer.

I see one real possibility: You're passing in a null to BuildingsLeft03's constructor for the target property from some external class constructing a BuildingsLeft03.

```
BuildingsLeft03(stage, 0, 0 null) //the null
```

This would make

```
target == null
target.hit //ERROR 1009
```

Comment: Thanks for looking. I changed public loop to private & still receive the same error. target.hit is the "hitBox" of my player class, which should work fine as this is the same method I'm using for taking damage from my enemy class. It's my understanding that the "null ref" means that the code is looking for something that hasn't been instantiated yet - target.hit should be & as far as I know - is instantiated on start through the Engine class.

Comment: Are you sure the BuildingsLeft03 object is being passes a Cowboy object when its constructor is called?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I'm passing Cowboy through Buildings03Left thinking that Buildings03Left will need a reference in which to apply the hitTest - this is also how my player/enemy hitTest seems to work. I just don't know.

Comment: That's correct, it will need a reference in order to check .hit. Are you sure you're instantiating the Cowboy before the BuildingsLeft03? Show whatever code is creating the Buildings and the Cowboy, if you can.

Comment: In your ObjectPlacer code, you are never instantiating the Cowboy (target = new Cowboy(stage)). Correct this -- and before the call to BuildingsLeft03(...) and this should fix your error.

Comment: The code now reflects the help I've received from Sam DeHaan. Thanks Sam. I added- target:Cowboy = new Cowboy(stage); -to ObjectPLacer's build01 function.
It seems to work however, my "hitTestObject" trace is going off well before my player class actually comes into contact with the "building03Left" 
It seems that the hitTestObject is going off just as Building03Left enters the playfield as opposed to when my "Cowboy" touches it.
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't believe you've included the code for the hitTestObject function, so I can't offer any advice there.

Comment: I'm using hitTestObject for player & enemy bullets but, that shouldn't have anything to do Buildings03Left. Buildings03Left has a hitTestObject in it's loop function but that is all. I tried posting a jpeg but the sites rules prevented me from doing so.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what Buildings03Left's hitTestObject is actually doing.