# AS3 - hitTestObject Collision Not Registering Correctly

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I had a problem with my hitTestObject collision detection a couple of days ago which has since been fixed ([How can I solve my hitTestObject Collision Null Object Ref Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947798/how-can-i-solve-my-hittestobject-collision-null-object-ref-error)) with the help of you folks (thanks).

My problem now is as such:

When my "enemy.hit" comes into contact with "player.hit" it registers as a hit - this is good.

When my "building.collide" comes into contact with "player.hit" it registers as a hit - this is good.

However, when my "building.collide" comes into contact with my "enemy.hit" it does not register, but sometimes it does register even though the only enemy on-screen is many pixels away from it - as if either the building or enemy "hitBox" is somewhere other than directly on the graphic(MovieClip in this case).

I don't understand how this could be. 
My enemy class has a hit.hitTestObject(player.hit) which works fine.
My building class has a collide.hitTestObject(player.hit) that also works fine.
So, it should reason that my building class collide.hitTestObject(enemy.hit) should also work fine - but it does not.
Any ideas?

My code consists of 10 or so .as files & I'm not entirely sure which of these is causing the problem. I don't want to be rude and post a 1000 lines of my amateur code for you to dig through -though, I will if need be.

Green parts are the hitBoxes (which is a layer within that particular MovieClip)

[image: gunslingersnapshot]

I hope this convoluted description is easy enough to follow.
Thank you for looking.

I think I know what is going on but, I have no idea how to correct it.
I use an ObjectPlacer class to place buildings, flora, fauna, etc and I believe that when I call - 
`var targetCowboy:Cowboy = new Cowboy(stageRef);
var enemyJoe:EnemyJoe = new EnemyJoe(stageRef, targetCowboy);
var Buildings03Left:BuildingsLeft03 = new BuildingsLeft03(stage, 0, -720, targetCowboy, enemyJoe);

            stageRef.addChildAt((Buildings03Left), 2);
            build01Place = false;`

That this is actually creating multiple instances of both Cowboy and EnemyJoe and this is what is confusing flash. How can I reference Cowboy and EnemyJoe without using "new"?(e.g. var targetCowboy:Cowboy = new Cowboy(stageRef);)

ObjectPlacer code:

```
    package com.gamecherry.gunslinger
    {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

public class  ObjectPlacer extends MovieClip
{

    private var Build01Timer:Timer;
    private var Build02Timer:Timer;
    private var CactiSet01Timer:Timer;

    private var build01Place:Boolean = false;// if true - addChild starts at first frame
    private var build02Place:Boolean = false;
    private var cactiSet01Place:Boolean = false;
    private var stageRef:Stage;


    public function ObjectPlacer(stageRef:Stage)
    {
        this.stageRef = stageRef;


    var Build01Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);
    var Build02Timer = new Timer(25000, 1);
    var CactiSet01Timer = new Timer(0, 1);


    Build01Timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, build01TimerHandler, false, 0, true);
    Build02Timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, build02TimerHandler, false, 0, true);
    CactiSet01Timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, cactiSet01TimerHandler, false, 0, true);

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);

        Build01Timer.start();
        Build02Timer.start();
        CactiSet01Timer.start();
    }


    public function loop(e:Event): void
    {
        BuildSet01();
        BuildSet02();
        CactiSet01();

    }   

    private function BuildSet01(): void
    {

        if (build01Place)
        {
        var Buildings01Right:BuildingsLeft = new BuildingsLeft(stage, 720, -624);   
        Buildings01Right.scaleX = -1;
        stageRef.addChildAt((Buildings01Right), 2);

        var targetCowboy:Cowboy = new Cowboy(stageRef);
        var enemyJoe:EnemyJoe = new EnemyJoe(stageRef, targetCowboy);
        var Buildings03Left:BuildingsLeft03 = new BuildingsLeft03(stage, 0, -720, targetCowboy, enemyJoe);              
        stageRef.addChildAt((Buildings03Left), 2);
        build01Place = false;


        }

    }

    private function BuildSet02(): void
    {

        if (build02Place)
        {

        var Buildings04Left:BuildingsLeft04 = new BuildingsLeft04(stage, 0, -800);
        stageRef.addChildAt((Buildings04Left), 2);
        build02Place = false;
        }
    }

    private function CactiSet01(): void
    {
        if (cactiSet01Place)
        {
            var cactus01:GScactus01 = new GScactus01(stage, 0, 300);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus01), 2);
            var cactus01b:GScactus01 = new GScactus01(stage, 190, 50);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus01b), 2);
            var cactus01c:GScactus01 = new GScactus01(stage, 660, -40);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus01c), 2);
            cactus01c.scaleX = -1;
            var cactus01d:GScactus01 = new GScactus01(stage, 710, 340);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus01d), 2);
            cactus01d.scaleX = -1;
            var cactus02:GScactus02 = new GScactus02(stage, 420, -50);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus02), 2);
            var cactus02b:GScactus02 = new GScactus02(stage, 600, 180);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus02b), 2);
            var cactus02c:GScactus02 = new GScactus02(stage, 300, 240);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus02c), 2);
            var cactus03:GScactus03 = new GScactus03(stage, 540, 100);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus03), 2);
            var cactus03b:GScactus03 = new GScactus03(stage, 30, 5);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus03b), 2);
            cactus03b.scaleX = -1;
            var cactus03c:GScactus03 = new GScactus03(stage, 520, 420);
            stageRef.addChildAt((cactus03c), 2);

            cactiSet01Place = false;
        }
    }



    private function build01TimerHandler(e: TimerEvent) : void
    {
        build01Place = true;
    }
    private function build02TimerHandler(e: TimerEvent) : void
    {
        build02Place = true;
    }


    private function cactiSet01TimerHandler(e: TimerEvent) : void
    {
        cactiSet01Place = true;
    }











    private function removeSelf() : void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

        if (stageRef.contains(this))
        stageRef.removeChild(this); 
    }   

}
```

}

Comment: post the "hit" property code and all the second hittest code. You also have some wierd hit text choices, building is given a "target" enemy, where are the other enemies checked against?

Comment: I thought it made more sense to have each "object" (buildings, cacti, boxes, etc) check against the one player & the few enemies rather than the player/enemies check against every single object in the game. So, in this case the building checks against player & enemy. I added the enemy/player check only to test if the enemy hitBox was indeed working(it seems to be)

Comment: I added some code to my question. Thanks for your interest

Comment: Can't find it, eludes me... I could probably debug this is 2 minutes with source access... if you want that, go to my profile, the "website" holds the first part of my email... add (at)gmail.com behind it to contact me. Why am I offering this? I plan on offering paid tutoring lessons sometime in the future but I can't arse myself to actually do it. So if you want to be my guinea pig to stress test the idea free of charge, I can teach you a few things... your oop coding is great/amazing for a newb, but it's atrocious past that (that's the biggest hurdle to cross though), I can nudge you in the

Comment: I can nudge you in the right direction. One thing though. You probably ain't gonna learn shit in that school though(your comment on your earlier quetion). The code you're going to work on is simpler then the code base you've developed for this game... :) consider my offer, If you arrent up for it, feel free to say no, I'll want to delete my info soon, so the sooner the better :) If you are up for it, i still need to delete that info so hurry up :)

Comment: As much as I appreciate the offer, I'll have to decline. Nothing against you - after all, it was you that figured out how to get my player class to shoot diagonally(thanks again). The main goal of this "game" is for me to learn AS3 and I feel that I would be cheating myself if I handed my work over to someone else to complete just as things were getting interesting. If however, you want to tutor me or run some lesson plans or ideas by me, then I am more than a willing subject. My email is in my profile. Feel free to contact me anytime and thanks again for your help.

Comment: I think I know what is causing my problem and I amended my question. If you could take another look, I could really use your expertise.

Comment: I never offered to complete the game for you :). I just offered to show you how to locate this particular issue. I never do someone elses work, though I don't mind teaching somebody how to do it :) You're email is only visible to you, others can't see it in your portal. Your idea regarding the problem only holds water if the ObjectPlacer is being initialised more then once, I don't how it can be instantialized multiple times if the code is as shown upstairs. Bug me on my email or place your own in the website field if you want tutoring :).

Comment: place "traces" in the ObjectPlacer constructor and in the if() of the BuildSet01 function to see how many times they fire... it prove or kill your theory :)

Comment: My email is: gamecherry@gamecherry.com

Comment: I know for a fact that this is causing multiple instances because: there was  an invisible EnemyJoe shooting at me that could interact with the stage but couldnt be killed(removed) which I got to go away by // that piece of code. Also, as the code is now - I have EnemyJoe instantiated on a timer. My player(Cowboy) fires like normal until EnemyJoe is instantiated then he fires his bullets from as many positions as there are enemyJoes. And Cowboy becomes quite sluggish. My thinking is, just like the invisble EnemyJoe - there are many invisible Cowboys each with the ability to shoot.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to be wary of is that `hitTestObject` does [AABB (axis-aligned bounding box) collision](http://lj9.mexinetica.com/fotogen/lidsol_motorj/figure0-aabbaabb.png), meaning that it fits a rectangle around your object, and uses that to test for collisions. Your buildings appear to have complex, concave shapes -- `hitTestObject` won't take these into consideration, it simply plops a giant rectangle over the building and uses that to test. Also note that if `collide` is a single MovieClip with all of the building areas inside of it, then the rectangle gets wrapped over that entire area as opposed to having separate areas for the individual buildings. You'd have to split your collision areas up into separate rectangles and test against them individually. This is likely why you are seeing some false positives and bad behavior.

[`hitTestPoint`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint%28%29) will take into account the object's shape and do pixel-perfect collision when the `shapeFlag` parameter set to true, but this will only test a single point. To test a larger shape, you can try to do multiple `hitTestPoint` calls iteratively. If that's not sufficient, look into more sophisticated collision methods. Check out [this set of tutorials](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) from the creators of N.

Comment: I know about the "rectangle". I have these hitBox shapes for later use when I apply a better collision detect system. Building should still detect collision with enemy when the enemy is "touching" the building, but it (sometimes) goes off when the enemy is no where near the building(like the other side of the screen)

Answer (score 0):

I long abandoned the builtin flash functions for collision detection in favor of my own system that uses the separating axis theorem for AABBs, or using something like Box2D to handle the physics for me.

I've never had success with either hitTestPoint or hitTestObject, but you might find that the bitmapData.hitTest will work for you (never used it), or you could go with a rectangle-based grid system for everything, which is what I do.