# Actionscript 3 - Bitmaps and Symbols

Tags: actionscript-3

I am working on flash professional cs5.5 and actionscript 3. I need to use symbols of customized sizes to test the `hitTestOjbect()` function. However, when i convert the bitmap to a symbol, by default it goes into a rectangular size and the empty space all around is also detected as part of the symbol.

Is there any way to keep the size of the symbol customized ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the nature of a bitmap. Technically, bitmaps are always rectangular. Transparent areas are just fills with alpha-0. When you convert a bitmap to a symbol, the bitmap still exists, just inside the context of the symbol.

One of the fastest ways to fix this is to use a mask inside your MovieClip. Create a plain drawing object in the exact shape of the hit area you want. Then, place that on your timeline on it's own layer. Right-click the layer with the mask, click "Mask", and then drag the bitmap's layer under the mask one. Lock both layers, and exit symbol editing.

Now your hit area will be limited to only the masked area.

EDIT: I appear to be mistaken - hitTestArea is always rectangular. See the top answer to [hitTestObject Collision Not Registering Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976222/as3-hittestobject-collision-not-registering-correctly).

Comment: thanks for the reply. however, masking is also resulting to the same problem. i am converting the bitmap to a movieclip, is that a problem behind it?? i am making a car racing game and during the game i have to detect if the car travels on the ground bypassing the road. i require the ground and the car both to be movieclips. can you please suggest me any solution regarding that??

Comment: EDIT: Ah, apparently hit test object is always rectangular. I edited with a link to an answer that should solve your problem.