# AS3 and General Animation Hitboxes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, geometry, line

I have a simple stickman running animation in flash as3, and I can't even begin to figure out how to gather the coordinates of the end of each stick in the stickman at every frame. So I have the coordinates of each line, height and width of the corresponding symbol. Really not sure what to do here to get those end points.

Now I would like help knowing how to do the above, but this also made me curious of how professional programmers define hitboxes on animations; Do animators have some sort of hitbox tool? Do programmers just code the hitboxes and test them to perfection? That sounds like a really hard way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3 - hitTestObject Collision Not Registering Correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976222/as3-hittestobject-collision-not-registering-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the best way to use hitboxes is to detect collision between two objects. If I understand your question correctly, this would do what you need.

There are two different ways of doing this. If you are okay with a straight rectangular hit box, you can use [`hitTestObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6). However, if you want the hitbox to be the same shape as the object in question, you can use [`hitTestPoint`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint%28%29).

Dealing with lines, obviously, might mean that the second option would make the hitbox far too small to be practical. You can resolve this by drawing a fully transparent shape inside your object that defines your custom hit area, and then using `hitTestPoint`.

There is more specific information about hitboxes in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21069020/472647) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6976222/472647). For future questions, you will want to look for a similar question first, before asking a new one. Check out [the rest of the rules here](https://stackoverflow.com/about), and [check the Help Center for more detailed rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help).